# Universal USER in Directorys?

Tags: c

I want to write some text to a text file but I need a universal USER at the directory.
E.g. C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test.txt

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<signal.h>
void main() {
    int i,l;
    FILE *fp;
    char text[255];
    char verz[255];
    char username[128];
    DWORD usernamelen;
    if(!GetUserName(username, &usernamelen)) {
        printf("Error %d occured\n", (int)GetLastError());
    }
    strcat(verz,"C:/Users/");
    strcat(verz,username);
    strcat(verz,"/Destktop/test.txt");
    printf("Dein Text: ");
    fgets(text, 255, stdin);
    fp = fopen(verz, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s",text);
}
```

I expect that there is a new file on the Desktop with some text in it.

Comment: So what happens instead?

Comment: `strcat(verz,"C:/Users/");` is undefined behaviour because `verz` isn't initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're composing your pathname you're doing

```
strcat(verz,"C:/Users/");
strcat(verz,username);
strcat(verz,"/Destktop/test.txt");
```

The problem is that `verz` is not initialized, so the first `strcat` invokes *undefined behaviour* because the string is not empty/nul-terminated.

Results may vary, in your case, the filename is not valid and no file is created, but you don't know this since you're not testing the return value of `fopen`:

```
fp = fopen(verz, "w");
fprintf(fp, "%s",text);
```

A quickfix would be:

```
strcpy(verz,"C:/Users/");
```

One line with `sprintf`, faster & clearer:

```
sprintf(verz,"C:/Users/%s/Desktop/test.txt",username);
fp = fopen(verz, "w");
if (fp!=NULL)
{
     fprintf(fp, "%s",text);
     fclose(fp);  // better close the file
}
```

Comment: Thank you now the string is correct but it shows me Error 112 because it can't get the username

Comment: you have to run it as administrator, windows won't let you write/read from user directory unless it's yours